# Does Encryption have an effect on the AI?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

I know that decryption has a combat advantage and allows you to view information more accurately, but does encryption effect the AI? I imagine against a player it would prevent them from seeing details about what you're doing, but does this affect the AI?

Is it a waste of time researching encryption in an AI only game?

Comment: First of all, your encryption counters their decryption. Researching it prevents the enemy from getting bonus from decryption advantage.

I don't know if that affects the AI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it only counters decryption to prevent the decryption advantage in battle, but I have yet to see an AI get a decryption advantage against me.

**Man the Guns**

According to this [Feedback Gaming Video](https://youtu.be/Na6SVxokT98), it affects ship spotting.